# Merge tables into one View with continous ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have following tables :

```
Answer1         |   Answer2     |   Answer3
AnswerID        |       ID      |   ID
QuestionnaireID |QuestionnaireId|   QuestID
EmployeeName    | Employeename  |   EmployeeName
PcName          |   PcName      |   PcName
Answer          |   AnswerText  |   Answer
AnswerDate      |   AnswerDate  |   Ans_Date
```

I want to create View in MS SQL Server and i want to merge these values into one view with fixed fieds but with one modification.
Every table has AnswerID(or ID) starting from 1. What I want to do is to make it continously increasing so if last AnswerId from Answer1 
is equal eg. 1000, adding records from answer2 will update Answer2.ID to be Answer2.ID + 1000.

```
CREATE VIEW Answer
AS
SELECT  a.AnswerID ID,
    a.Answer Text,
    a.AnswerDate Date,
FROM    Answer1 a
```

What should I do now? I guess JOIN is not method to do such task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing this, as returning new id from view is not going to help you by any means, but still if you want unique id for each tables, you can try like following.

```
WITH TBL1 AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) [NewId], * FROM Answer1
),    
 TBL2 AS
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY ID) 
     + (SELECT MAX([NewId]) FROM TBL1) AS [NewId2],* FROM Answer2
),    
TBL3 AS 
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY ID) 
      + (SELECT MAX([NewId2]) FROM TBL2) AS RN2,* FROM Answer3
)
SELECT * FROM TBL1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TBL2
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TBL3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want continuous values, why not just use `row_number()` and re-assign all the ids?

```
select AnswerID as ID, a.Answer as Text, a.AnswerDate as Date,
       row_number() over (order by which, id) as new_id
from ((select a.*, 1 as which from answer1 a) union all
      (select a.*, 2 as which from answer2 a) union all
      (select a.*, 3 as which from answer3 a)
     ) a;
```